# Пауза потока до ответа

Tags: c#, wpf, вконтакте, vkontakte-api

Реализую отправку сообщений через ВК АПИ, в отдельном потоке происходит отправка последовательно нескольких сообщений, соответственно бывает нужно ввести капчу. всё нужно перехватываю, но как реализовать что бы во время срабатывания исключения можно было обработать таким образом, что бы поток не возобновлялся, пока пользователь не введет код? (WPF C#)

```
  private async void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        string[] id = new string[10];
        id[0] = "258722173";
        id[1] = "258722173";
        id[2] = "258722173";
        id[3] = "258722173";
        id[4] = "258722173";
        id[5] = "258722173";
        id[6] = "258722173";
        id[7] = "258722173";
        id[8] = "258722173";
        id[9] = "258722173";
        VKLSMessage vkls = new VKLSMessage("258722173", vk.AccessToken, textBox.Text);
        try
        {
            await vk.SendFromList(id, vkls);
        }
        catch
        {
            MessageBox.Show("ccskrf" + vkls.CaptchaUri);
            BitmapImage BI = new BitmapImage(new Uri(vkls.CaptchaUri));

            image.Source = BI;


        }

      // vk.AutoSendMessageTrigger(new VKLSMessage("258722173", vk.AccessToken,  textBox.Text));
    }



public async Task SendFromList(string[] _list,VKLSMessage _message)
        {
            _AutoSendActiv = !_AutoSendActiv;
            cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
            for (int i =0;i<_list.Length; i++)
            {
                _message.UserId = _list[i];
                _message.Send();
                if(i!= _list.Length-1)
                await Task.Delay(2);
                if (!_AutoSendActiv)
                {
                    cts.Cancel();
                    break;
                }
            }
           // MessageBox.Show("Отправка окончена");
            _AutoSendActiv = false;
            cts = null;
        }




    public string Send()
    {
        int a = 0;

        replay:
        string mes = HttpRequest.GET_http(VkUri.GetMessageSendUri(this));

        if (mes.Contains("Captcha needed"))
        {

            CaptchaUri = VkUri.GetCaptchaUri(mes);
            CaptchaSid = VkUri.GetCaptchaSid(mes);

            throw new System.InvalidOperationException("Captcha needed");

        }

        if (mes.Contains("Flood control: same message already sent") && a >= 5)
        {
            throw new System.InvalidOperationException("Error: Flood control: same message already sent" + a);
        }
        if (mes.Contains("Flood control: same message already sent"))
        {
            a++;
            goto replay;
        }

        return mes;
    }
```

Comment: Без примера кода вряд-ли можно чем-то тут помочь

Comment: @GeorgePolevoy Добавил примерно свзанные методы. но они не из одного класса

Comment: А почему не создать окно с кнопкой OK и полем ввода, и не показать его через ShowDialog?

Comment: @vladd Впринцципе пока что так и сделал, но кажется мне это может не подойти.